# Would this be a free variable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let's say I have the RREF matrix

$$ A= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

If i'm looking for the solution of this matrix, would it be correct to say that since all columns have a pivot entry except for column two, that it would be the only free variable?
So...

$1x_{1} + 3x_{2} + 0x_{3} + 0x_{4} = 0$

$0x_{1} + 0x_{2} + 1x_{3} + 0x_{4} = 0$

$0x_{1} + 0x_{2} + 0x_{3} + 1x_{4} = 0$

$x_{1} = -3x_{2}$

$x_{3} = 0$

$x_{4} = 0$

Ummm... this is where I am stuck. Since this does not look right, what am I doing wrong? 
I want to write the solution in vector form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing nothing wrong. The variable $x_2$ is free, so you can give it any value whatsoever; the solutions are the vectors of the form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-3h\\h\\0\\0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
for $h$ any scalar.